# Is There a Way To Simulate the Form Activate from Modal/Pop Up Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a form that opens a modal pop up helper form to collect some data. When this modal pop up form closes, focus returns to the main form. I would like to trigger some activity when focus comes back to my main form.

The event model for the form does not trigger the `Form_Activate` or `Form_GotFocus` events when returning from a model popup as per Microsoft documentation.

These forms and all controls are completely unbound.

Is there a trick to knowing in code when focus returns to my form?

If both forms are placed in normal mode, `Form_Activate` does fire in the primary form when the helper form closes, but this does not meet my needs. I have not been able to find a similar event to trap this. I'm hoping someone has a workaround.

Comment: How are you closing the helper form? Could you capture the `QueryClose` event of your helper form and use that to execute whatever `Form_Activate` is supposed to do on your main form? Could you use it to remporarily hide the helper form, which returns execution to wherever it was originally shown (and from that spot in your main form you could manually call `Form_Activate`)?

Comment: If your form is modal, then execution resumes on the line immediately following `childForm.Show vbModal` after `childForm` gets closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, the issue I ran into was I had the design time properties in the helper form set to act as a dialog - (pop up and modal as true). When I opened the form responding to the button click event on the main form, I did NOT include the `acDialog` option.

If you omit the `WindowMode=acDialog` setting the code operates asynchronously completing the code in the click event handler in full, NOT halting and waiting.

The `acDialog` option apparently forces the `DoCmd.OpenForm` command to run synchronously, halting code execution, then returning once the modal form has been closed.

```
    Private Sub btnHelper_Click()

        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmHelper", WindowMode:=acDialog

        'Do stuff after frmHelper closes

    End Sub
```

Comment: hmm is that a `UserForm` or an "Access form"?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. It's both. It's simply a form I built in Access. Nothing special, in this case, it's actually called frmPermit. It collects permit data associated with a vehicle profile, I changed the names to be generic for the question as to not distract.

Comment: As you note, opening the form as dialog halts calling code. A popup form is a MASSIVLY different kind of form and is for a different use and does NOT halt calling code. I should also point out that a model form is ALSO A MASSILVY different kind of form and is for a different use. So don't confuse model, popup and dialog forms - they are all very spectacular different and are for different kinds of uses. And ignore the suggestions about user forms as they don't apply to access. And ignore the example with .show vbModel - it does not work nor apply to Access forms.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal undoubtfully you meant **modal** / `vbModal`, not *model*.